# ConstraintLayout Does Not Work Properly in a Bottom Sheet View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

## Issue

The ConstraintLayout does not work as expected when used in a Bottom sheet. In this instance a ConstraintLayout contains 2 images comprising the handle and 1 view for the content in the Bottom Sheet. The content view is supposed to be placed below the handle images which is not happening.

### Implementation

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_handle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_bottom_sheet_handle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/saved_bottomsheet_handle_content_description"
                android:elevation="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_save_planet_dark_48dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_elevation_height"
                android:background="@color/bottom_sheet_handle_elevation"
                android:contentDescription="@string/saved_bottomsheet_handle_content_description"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_handle" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/savedContentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_handle" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Result

The Actionbar from the content view is floating behind the handle views.

[image]

## Expected Result

The handle sits above the content view and Action Bar.

[image]

## Possible Solution

As much as I'd rather use the ConstraintLayout over RelativeLayout, RelativeLayout works here.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_handle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_bottom_sheet_handle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/saved_bottomsheet_handle_content_description"
                android:elevation="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_save_planet_dark_48dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_elevation_height"
                android:background="@color/bottom_sheet_handle_elevation"
                android:contentDescription="@string/saved_bottomsheet_handle_content_description"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bottom_handle"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_below="@id/bottom_handle"
                android:id="@+id/savedContentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have same problem with bottomsheetdialogfragment, but I have not tried to use RelativeLayout instead of ConstrainLayout. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd recommend not using a RelativeLayout and [fixing the existing ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116916/2253682).

Comment: I spent many hours figuring out the reason of problem, but the height of ConstraintLayout was always 0 (constraints (bottom/start/...) was setted)

Comment: I find sometimes that using a [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline) with a percentage can help, especially if the view needs to have the same ratio across screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `match_parent` for children of `ConstraintLayout` is not recommended as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout):

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a
>   ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using
>   MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom
>   constraints being set to "parent".

In your case setting height to `match_parent` for the `FrameLayout` causes it to take the parent's height regardless of the constraints.

Instead of using `match_parent` you should add the bottom constraint for your `FrameLayout` and use `0dp` to `match_constraint` for height:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/savedContentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_handle" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try by changing this in constraint layout

```
<FrameLayout
 ....

     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
>
```